# Python Dictionary Reverse Simple

Tags: python, dictionary

I only want to do a very simple think, not reverse the key to value but only reverse the order of dictionary
from

```
{'a':1, 'f':3: 'd':2}
```

to this

```
{'d':2, 'f':3: 'a':1}
```

I don't need key value switching like some many solution out there..
Yes it's doesn't mean anything in the functionality but i just need that for "eye catching" json structure.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not 100.00% a duplicate, but the point is that you're asking how to order a dictionary - which is explained in multiple questions elsewhere. Dictionaries can't be sorted by definition

Comment: @TerryA I know what you mean, but the English meanings of the last sentence may make it confusing for a newer user or an ESL speaker, on account of how real-world dictionaries have definitions in the same way that Python dictionaries have values.

Comment: @TerryA, yes i just need something like list.reverse() in list..

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945473/how-to-reverse-a-dictionary-in-python, or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436595/python-reverse-dictionary is not the answer